# Let X,Y be bivariate normal , what is E[X|Z] where Z = X + Y?

Tags: conditional-expectation, bivariate

I am trying to understand how does expectation and variance looks when

Let X,Y be bivariate normal

I want understand E[X|Z] and Var[X|Z]

when Z = X + Y

Comment: $(X,Z)$ is also bivariate normal, so $X$ given $Z$ is univariate normal.

Comment: This is a FAQ: search our site for [conditional normal expectation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=conditional+normal+expect*).